# transforming / updating / typecasting list values from int & num to strings

Tags: mysql, r, rscript

I'm retrieving data from a MySQL database using an R script and then writing it to a CSV, but I'm having an issue where two of the columns of data that I want to write out as strings are being written out as integers and numbers (in this case, in scientific notation).

I would like to have these written out as string values instead, but I'm not finding this is a straightforward task, in spite of doing a fair bit of googling and experimentation.

The relevant code:

```
conn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), host = "127.0.0.1", user="REDACTED", password="REDACTED", dbname="REDACTED", port=8906)
type_data <- dbGetQuery(conn, paste("SELECT * FROM ", arg, " WHERE 1 LIMIT 10", sep=""))

# Problem: "Subscribed" and "TimeUpdated" are coming through as numbers instead of strings

write.csv(type_data, paste("./",arg,".csv", sep=""), row.names=F)
dbDisconnect(conn)
```

Desired results:

```
"Id","EntityId","EntityType","CommunicationType","Subscribed","TimeUpdated"
"0002INKRyUolIrjG5DbUa0lDqUjxt","4374484","PERSON","MFS","1","1385297883000000000"
"0004WaXpmvbOh3WG3hd6kQtPINibv","8361929","PERSON","MFS","1","1437798832740631885"
"0005l1fy1TJiFhyiEK2IXRCxfqee5","4197014","PERSON","SURVEYS_AND_POLLS","0","1146917239000000000"
"0008Qb2ra1PoSLgbumc2wmDfvexx8","4155704","PERSON","MFS","1","1345053223000000000"
"000C1IKgHrFaqmlHlKGGhigGyoaw4","4515071","PERSON","PARTNER","1","1215098959000000000"
"000Czw8Gv5w3eNoOmOFVTKLIuc2ti","4372360","PERSON","MFS","1","1384952236000000000"
"000DOsk9xlYKvs11PzZFRgmOpYfiA","4347384","PERSON","SURVEYS_AND_POLLS","1","1177513307000000000"
"000IQ4TKYHAbb334zFYdWVCZZfMYo","4470083","PERSON","PARTNER","1","1446945757133940400"
"000LbifV4rUa2MhxFlVZ52PSek5kG","499194","PERSON","SURVEYS_AND_POLLS","0","1097867573000000000"
```

Actual results:

```
"Id","EntityId","EntityType","CommunicationType","Subscribed","TimeUpdated"
"0002INKRyUolIrjG5DbUa0lDqUjxt","4374484","PERSON","MFS",1,1.385297883e+18
"0004WaXpmvbOh3WG3hd6kQtPINibv","8361929","PERSON","MFS",1,1437798832740631808
"0005l1fy1TJiFhyiEK2IXRCxfqee5","4197014","PERSON","SURVEYS_AND_POLLS",0,1.146917239e+18
"0008Qb2ra1PoSLgbumc2wmDfvexx8","4155704","PERSON","MFS",1,1.345053223e+18
"000C1IKgHrFaqmlHlKGGhigGyoaw4","4515071","PERSON","PARTNER",1,1.215098959e+18
"000Czw8Gv5w3eNoOmOFVTKLIuc2ti","4372360","PERSON","MFS",1,1.384952236e+18
"000DOsk9xlYKvs11PzZFRgmOpYfiA","4347384","PERSON","SURVEYS_AND_POLLS",1,1.177513307e+18
"000IQ4TKYHAbb334zFYdWVCZZfMYo","4470083","PERSON","PARTNER",1,1446945757133940480
"000LbifV4rUa2MhxFlVZ52PSek5kG","499194","PERSON","SURVEYS_AND_POLLS",0,1.097867573e+18
"000OWvUHdmjeL34XzuVLmHQBple7X","4176205","PERSON","MFS",1,1.143985154e+18
```

Assistance would be most appreciated!

Comment: Convert the `TimeUpdated` to character before writing to csv.

Comment: Have you tried converting the columns "Subscribed" and "TimeUpdated" with as.character() such as in type_date$Subscribed <- as.character(type_data$Subscribed) ?

Comment: @Bernhard definitely on the right track, thanks. Issue now is TimeUpdated ends up like "1.146917239e+18", whereas I just want "1385297883000000000".

Comment: @Bernhard never mind, I figured it out. Thanks for your assistance! And yes, I'm a huge noob with R. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bernhard for the help with this - here's a working solution.

```
options(scipen = 999) # so that TimeUpdated isn't outputted using scientific notation

conn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), host = "127.0.0.1", user="REDACTED", password="REDACTED", dbname="REDACTED", port=8906)
type_data <- dbGetQuery(conn, paste("SELECT * FROM ", arg, " WHERE 1", sep=""))

# convert the subscribed and timeupdated columns to strings
type_data$Subscribed <- as.character(type_data$Subscribed)
type_data$TimeUpdated <- as.character(type_data$TimeUpdated)

write.csv(type_data, paste(args[[1]], "/", arg, ".csv", sep=""), row.names=F)
dbDisconnect(conn)
```